# How do I resolve a 503 Response code when installing/configuring FishEye?

Tags: installation, configure, atlassian-fisheye

I'm trying to install/configure FishEye as per the instructions on Atlassian's website, but either the web server for the install doesn't start properly (and I see multiple exception message in the command window), or I get a 503 Response code when I try to access the installation link.

How can I get past this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [installation instructions](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/FISHEYE/Installing+FishEye) currently aren't clear, especially on a Windows environment.

Here's what you need to do (in my case on a Windows system).

1. Extract the fisheye archive to the directory where you're intending to run Fisheye from. (on my system, I made this <drive>:\Atlassian\FishEye).
2. Create a directory for your data. (I made this <drive>:\Application Data\FishEye)
3. Create an environment variable (Window System Variable) named 'FISHEYE_INST' and set it to the path you created in Step 2. ('INST' in this case means *instance* and not *installation folder*.
4. Copy the 'config.xml' file from <extracted_archive> to your FISHEYE_INST folder.
5. Open a command prompt and run the <extracted archive>\bin\run.bat file. (ie :\Atlassian\FishEye\bin\run.bat).

   - The online documentation is a little misleading at this point. They indicate that you run 'start.bat', which won't work (or at least, it wouldn't work for me...)
6. Open a browser and point it to 'http://localhost:8060'.

Following the steps above let me get FishEye up and running without any further issues.